# Unexpected behavior using cbind with edited ggplotGrobs

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I've been trying to edit some plots created by ggplot2 using the functions provided by the packages grid and gridExtra.  I realize that ggplot2 alone can make some really nice multifaceted plots.  However, in some instances I like to create individual plots and then combine then together later on.  While trying to do just that, I came across some unexpected behavior using `cbind()` with `grid.draw()` or `grid.arrange()` when using a ggplot2 graph that had been edited.  Below is the code for an MWE:

```
#Load libraries
    library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra)

#Load data
    data(mtcars)

#Ggplot
    p = qplot(wt,mpg,data=mtcars,color=cyl)
    grob = ggplotGrob(p)

#Bold xlabel
    grobEdited = editGrob(grid.force(grob),gPath("xlab","GRID.text"),grep=TRUE,gp=gpar(fontface="bold"))

#Visualize
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(grobEdited)
```

[image]

It worked as expected.  Now to illustrate the issue, lets `cbind()` two of the same edited ggplot2 graphs:

```
#Cbind example with edited graphs
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(cbind(grobEdited,grobEdited))
```

[image]

It didn't work as expected!  Now test `cbind()` on the unedited graphs:

```
#Cbind example with grob
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(cbind(grob,grob))
```

[image]

Works as expected.  I'm new to gridded figures, so is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is with the `grid.force()` call.  Documentation suggests that drawing the result may not make sense in a different drawing context. Are you able to remove that part of the code?

Comment: @ryan-morton `grid.force()` allows the editing functions to have access to all of the grobs in the ggplot2 graph, so in this context I believe it is necessary.  I guess I could manually edit the grob w/o using the editing functions (which will make thinks a lot more difficult).

Comment: Maybe try `cbind`ing before the edit.. `grobEdited = editGrob(grid.force(cbind(grob, grob)),
                          gPath("xlab","GRID.text"), global=TRUE,
                          grep=TRUE,gp=gpar(fontface="bold", col="red"))`

Comment: (or maybe `grid.arrange` is okay for your needs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer following the comment from @user20650.  The easiest workaround is to `cbind()` the ggplot2 graphs before editing them using the editing functions provided by `grid` or `gridExtra`:

```
#Edit after cbind()                              
    grobEdited = editGrob(grid.force(cbind(grob,grob)),gPath("xlab","GRID.text"),global=TRUE,grep=TRUE,gp=gpar(fontface="bold"))

#Visualize
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(grobEdited)
```

[image]